# camera setParameters not working in android 4.0.1 and 4.0.2

Tags: android, android-camera, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I'm developing an application that works fine on all the pre ice cream sandwich android versions as well as ICS 4.0.3. However for the Galaxy Nexus with versions 4.0.1 and 4.0.2 it force closes when I call Camera.setParameters()

My code snippet is given below

```
// mCamera is my camera object.
// mFrameWidth and mFrameHeight are my desired preview size
Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
List<Camera.Size> sizes = params.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
width = mFrameWidth;
height = mFrameHeight;

// selecting optimal camera preview size closest to desired size
double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
     if (Math.abs(size.width - width) < minDiff) {
         mFrameWidth = size.width;
         mFrameHeight = size.height;
         minDiff = Math.abs(size.width - width);
     }
 }
 params.setPreviewSize(mFrameWidth, mFrameHeight);

 // Crashes here
 mCamera.setParameters(params);
```

This is the crash report

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: setParameters failed
at android.hardware.Camera.native_setParameters(Native Method)
at android.hardware.Camera.setParameters(Camera.java:1295)
at com.example.MySurfaceView.surfaceChanged(MySurfaceView.java:182)
at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:544)
at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:81)
at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:169)
at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:590)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1617)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

It seemed like this problem was being caused by some bug in the ICS versions 4.0.1 and 4.0.2, but i couldn't find any bugs or issues related to this. It would be great if someone could point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, welcome to the fragmentation of Android. Dealing with cameras is where the fragmentation rears its ugly head. Each device will respond to different parameters and there's no guarantee as to what those will be. You simply have to test. Once you nail down which device responds to what, you do runtime checks for specific devices or API versions to set the appropriate parameters.

Comment: Yes, I've unfortunately had my fair share of dealing with issues caused by android fragmentation. However since I could find no bugs related to this, and also I could find no other phone running ICS 4.0.1/4.0.2 I thought maybe I'd missed something trivial, I'll file it as a bug and see if anyone responds.

Comment: What I'm saying is that I don't think it's a bug or necessary related to 4.0. It's simply the hardware of the Galaxy Nexus failing to respond to certain parameters. Try removing all parameters and adding them back in one at a time and see if you can find the offending parameter.

Comment: The preview size is the only parameter being set. And I've ascertained that the same code works in the Galaxy Nexus 4.0.3.

Comment: Same issue here - works fine on 2.3.3 and crashes on 4.0.2 (Galaxy Nexus)

Comment: I am wondering: how does the camera on the 4.0.2 nexus behave in general? I mean the app provided with the phone, especially if you mess around with some of its parameters (not programming wise, but in regard to what the camera dialog offers)

Answer (score 1):

In http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html you'll see that

> "This [Camera] class is not thread-safe, and is meant for use from one event thread. ... This class's methods must never be called from multiple threads at once."

Are you trying to call all of those methods in setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer() or setPreviewCallback()? Both of them will create new threads.

Another note: You should only be doing that code to change parameters when the preview is stopped.

I'm having the same problem now also; the exact code works in 2.2, but not 4.0+.